# Replacing DoubleQuote With SingleQuote in PHP Coding / Adsense

Tags: php, double-quotes

I'm using a php script to hold my adsense code for display, like so:

```
$ad_header_1 = "
    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:inline-block;width:320px;height:50px"
         data-ad-client="ca-pub-0000000000000000"
         data-ad-slot="0000000000"></ins>
    <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
";
```

Because this code has `"` symbols I have to escape them with a `\`, but is it valid/correct to change the DoubleQuote for a SingleQuote instead of having to escape them?

Comment: why shouldn't it? both are just different ways of encoding strings in your source code. personally, i even find it cleaner than escaping.

Comment: Yes, that's what I would like to use this method for. I just didn't know if it would affect the adsense results if you weren't using their **official** code

Comment: just think of this: *how*'d they ever know? and *why*'d they care?

Comment: Waht I mean is, my site relies on the Adverts for revenue, so obviously I don't want any changes I make to the original code to affect the potential revenue output.

Comment: *how* you encode the string in PHP won't even matter at the point when it passes through the *web server*, and definitely not when it hits the browser. and except if you got a ultraspecial deal with google which says they can peek at your code at any given time and can withhold payment for arbitrary reasons, it *does not matter*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can alter the outside double quotes to single quotes IF you are not relying on any variables being evaluated within the string.

So in your case, you can use single quotes to wrap your string.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ad_header_1 = '
    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:inline-block;width:320px;height:50px"
         data-ad-client="ca-pub-0000000000000000"
         data-ad-slot="0000000000"></ins>
    <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
';
```

In this way you can use your google adsense script